# Browser not sending cookies for cross-origin request using Fetch API (Firefox)

Tags: firefox, cookies, fetch, cross-domain

On a given domain (https://example.com) I have set cookies using `SameSite=None; Secure; HttpOnly`

On another site (https://example.org) I am making a fetch request:

```
fetch('https://example.com/secure/', {method: 'GET', credentials: 'include'})
```

From what I can see looking in Firefox's network tab there's no pre-flight OPTIONS request being sent. The GET request contains a `Host` header, `Origin` header but no `Cookies` header. The response contains `access-control-allow-credentials: true`, `access-control-allow-origin: https://example.org` and `vary: origin, true`

The response from example.com is returning a 401 due to no cookie being sent.

I can't figure out how to make the browser send cookies (I'm also not certain this is isolated to Firefox).

Comment: Ah yes the classic SO question that looks so tempting but offers no answers! Unfortunately I have to disappoint, it seems that Firefox is very unhelpful when it comes to sending or accepting cookies cross-origin. We've recently had the opposite problem whereby setting a cookie in a CORs request doesn't work either - the browser just ignores it